# An explanation on probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let be any probability space on the Borel measurable sets and let take a continous random variable there ... 
My question is ... What do the density function means here? .
On a discrete random variable our density function tell us the actual probability of an outcome but what means $f(x_0)$ on a countinous domain. 
If the probability on the continumm only have sense on non-zero measurable sets then does the density function on a continuum have sense to be defined on all Borel-measurable sets ?

Comment: Your first sentence seems to be missing some symbols, so it's not entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: First, discrete random variables have *probability mass functions* which, as you say, give probabilities of events like $X=k$ for an integer valued $X$ and integer $k$. Mass functions are not the same as density functions and they behave differently from one another. Densities are exactly as they are named: probabilities per unit, so naturally they will behave different than mass functions (e.g. it is possible for a density $f$ of some continuous RV to have $f(x)>1$ for some point $x$ but this never happens for mass functions of discrete RVs).

Answer (score 2):

On discrete random variables it is not a "density" in the sense that we understand density in the real physical world (like the density of a fluid), it is more like a "mass point" function.

The density in a continuous random variable $X$ is just a function $f_X$ such that

$$
\Pr\big(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in A\}\big)=\int_A f_X(x)\,dx\tag1
$$

for any Lebesgue measurable set $A\subset\Bbb R$. That is: a random variable is generally a real-valued function $X:\Omega\to \Bbb R$ that transport a probability measure $\Pr$ defined in $\Omega$ to a probability measure $\mu_X$ in $\Bbb R$ defined by the integral of the RHS of $\rm (1)$ (assuming that $X$ is continuous and have a density associated to it).

Note that $\rm (1)$ is generally shortened to just $\Pr[X\in A]$. Im not sure if this answers your question, I mean, I doesn't see a simple intuitive meaning of $f_X$ more than to be the derivative of the distribution of $X$.