# Probability: PMF vs PDF question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If:
$$
P(X = a) =\int_a^a f_X(z) \, dz = 0
$$

and if $f_X(z)$ is the probability for value of a random variable, is the following form possible?  If not, why?

$$
P(X = a) = f_X(a)
$$

I suspect this has something to do with the continuous case vs discrete PMF $\rho_X(a)$

Comment: An example is the uniform distribution, $X\sim U(l,u)$. Here $P(X=\alpha)=f_X(\alpha)=0 \ \  \forall \ \ u<\alpha<l$

Comment: You are confusing a discrete and an absolutely continuous random variable.

Comment: @WillM. can you explain further?

Comment: What do you mean by "if $f_X(z)$ is the probability for value of a random variable"? Is $f_X(z)$ the PDF, or the probability of something?

Comment: @joe I may be confusing the PDF and PMF?  I understand the PMF is $p_X(z) = P(X^{-1}[{z}])$ which is a probability and that the PDF is $F_X(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z f_X(a) da$ also a probability but continuous.  Does that help?

Comment: @callculus The uniform distribution PDF is $1/(b-a)$ from $[a,b]$.  Does $f_X(z)$ not reflect the probability of a random variable in that interval?

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350123/an-explanation-on-probability), it could help. However your question is so broad to be answered here. Its better that you read an introductory book on probability theory to understand this topic.

Comment: @Nick, if $b=0.5$ and $a=0$, then can $1/(b-a)$ be a probability? The PDF is a function that satisfies the definition that you gave in terms of the CDF, but its value at a point is not a probability.

Comment: @Nick sometimes people use the term probability density for both the actual density as well as the function $k \mapsto \mathbf{P}(X = k)$ in the case of a discrete random variable.

Comment: @Joe Helpful!  It seems I wrongly applied the PMF properties to the PDF.  I see PDF is $P(t < X < t + dt) = f_X(t) dt$ such that it is the relative probability is of X falling in a range vs the PDF which is the absolute probability of taking on one or a set of values.  Wiki also says the absolute probability of a PDF is 0, which agrees with the OP.  I think now I'm confused by 1. the relative vs absolute likelihood or probability.

Comment: @WillM. yes, I have typically seen $p_X(k) = P(X = k)$ for those forms and some other tricky ones when conditions are used with RVs.

Comment: I just read the wiki you mentioned. I don't remember ever seeing PDFs described that way before, and I don't think its particularly helpful, but I think by "relative" probability it means that, if there are two intervals of the same width, and $f_X(x)=c_1$ on the first interval and $f_X(x)=c_2\ne 0$ on the second interval, then the probability that the random variable is observed in the first interval is $c_1/c_2$ times the probability that the random variable is observed in the second interval.

Comment: @Joe or it could mean relative to the "unit" where $f_X(z) = {probability} / {unit}$

Comment: Maybe. I haven't seen it described that way before. I think the definition in terms of the CDF that you have in an earlier comment is the best way to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to explain it shortly, the more important notion for a random variable $Z$ is it **distribution function**, that is defined by

$$
F_Z(c):=\Pr [Z\leqslant c]
$$

Now let $X$ a random variable, then if $F_X$ is absolutely continuous then it is differentiable almost everywhere (respect to the Lebesgue measure), and so there is a function $f_X$ (called the *density function* of $X$) such that

$$
F_X(c)=\int_{\mathbb{R} }\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,c]}(t)f_X(t) \mathop{}\!d t
$$

However note that, when $X$ have a density (that is, when $F_X$ is absolutely continuous) then it holds that

$$
\Pr [X=c]=\Pr [X\leqslant c]-\Pr [X<c]
\\=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,c]}(t)f_X(t)\mathop{}\!d t-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,c)}f_X(t)\mathop{}\!d t
\\=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{\{c\}}(t)f_X(t)\mathop{}\!d t=0
$$

But, in general, $f_X(c)\neq 0$.

By the other side, if $Y$ is a discrete random variable with support in $\mathbb{Z}$, then the corresponding distribution function $F_Y$ is a staircase function, that is, a function that is constant in every interval of the form $[k,k+1)$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, therefore

$$
\Pr [Y=k]=\Pr [Y\leqslant k]-\Pr [Y<k]\\
=F_Y(k)-\Pr [Y\leqslant k-1]=F_Y(k)-F_Y(k-1)
$$

And we define $\rho_Y (k):=F_Y(k)-F_Y(k-1)$ and call $\rho _Y$ the *probability mass function* of $Y$.

Comment: What is the definition for $\mathbf 1_x$?

Comment: $\mathbf{1}_A(x)$ is an indicator function that is 1 when $x\in A$ and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just briefly state some definitions and some popular conventions.

### Distributions

Every real-valued RV has a cumulative distribution function (CDF):
$$F_X(x):= \mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$$
This is really the fundamental object for RVs. See @masacroso's answer. An important take away is that every RV, discrete or continuous, has a CDF.

### Discrete RVs

Discrete RVs take on countablly many values. That means they can take on a value in a set that looks like $\{x_1,\dotsc, x_n\}$ or $\{x_1, \dotsc \}$. A Bernoulli takes values in $\{0,1\}$, a Poisson RV in $\{0,1,2,\dotsc \}$.

For discrete RVs, the CDF is made up by summing over what is defined and called the probability mass function
$$P(X \leq k)=\sum_{j \leq k} P(X=j)$$
The function $j\to P(X=j)$ is the PMF and it's values are probabilities, i.e. values in $[0,1]$ satisfying all the axioms of probability. If $j$ is outside the support of the RV, then $P(X=j)=0$, otherwise it is non-zero. This is by definition, or convention. For example if $N$ is Poisson distributed, $P(N=\sqrt{4})$ is non-zero, while $P(N=\sqrt{2})=0$, since $\sqrt{2}$ is not a positive integer, so no Poisson RV, no matter how many samples you take, will ever take on its value.

### Continuous RVs

Now, I will not try to be general here, but when $F_X(x)$ is differentiable, we call its derivative the probability density function. This *is not a probability*, it is a *density*, literally, a probability per unit, so that intuitively, integrating over a region ought to give us a probability of being in that region: $\int_a^b f(x)dx = P(a \leq X \leq b)$. Because of this relation between PDF and CDF, we see that $P(X=a)=0$ for any continuous RV $X$ and any real $a$ *regardless if $a$ is in the range of $X$ or not*.

Just as in the discrete case, we take the convention that $f_X(x)$ is zero outside of , what is called, its support. So for the uniform distribution we have $f_X(x)=1/(b-a)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ and $f_X(x)=0$, for all other real $x<a$ or $x >b$. The Gaussian distribution is non-zero on the whole line, so you do not need to mention this sort of piece-wise convention that extends the PDF to the whole real line. An exponentially distributed RV's density function is only non-zero only on $(0,\infty)$, and so on.

Finally, we do not write $P(X=a)=f_X(a)$ because of the definition of PDFs and CDFs. The LHS is always equal to $\int_a^a f_X(x) dx=0$ for any $a$, and the RHS is just some value of the density, it may or may not be zero depending if $a$ is in the support of $X$ or not. It is best to entirely separate the notations for these reasons.

Comment: You mention probability / unit being the value of the PDF.  This is helpful because $\int_a^b f_X(z) dz = $ (probability / unit) * unit = probability.  Wiki describes the PDF $f_X(t) dt$ as the relative probability is of X falling in a range vs the PMF which is the absolute probability of taking on one or a set of values.  My guess at the meaning is the unit being in the denominator allows comparison between two values of PDF using common unit.  Do you have any idea on this?